# Bootstrap 3 - set height of modal window according to screen size

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a kind of responsive megamenu using Bootstrap 3 modal dialog. I would like to set the width and height of the whole modal window to 80% of the viewport, while setting the modal-body to a max-height in order not to populate the whole screen on large viewports.

My HTML:

```
    <div class="modal fade">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-megamenu">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Mega Menu Test</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary">close</button>
                    </div>
             </div>
        </div>
```

My CSS:

```
.modal-megamenu {
    width:80%;
    height:80%;
}

.modal-body {
    max-height:500px;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

This works as intended for the width, but the "height" parameter doesn't give any result. Like that, the height of the modal window is always set to the max-height value. Does anybody have an idea of how to set the height dynamically according to the viewport height?

Comment: I assume you are looking something similar to this -> http://jsfiddle.net/KanvL/1/

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65199651/7186739

Answer (score 85):

Pure CSS solution, using [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

```
.modal-body {
    max-height: calc(100vh - 200px);
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

*200px may be adjusted in accordance to height of header & footer*

Comment: Excellent answer, works perfectly. Just remember to check browser support (http://caniuse.com/#search=calc), not all versions supports it.

Comment: I think, this answer is based on this original post from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23324116/2091181) 2 years ago.

Comment: Son-of-a.... and I've been doing window resize listeners in JS for *how* long?!? I had NO idea the `vh` unit existed. Thanks very much!

Comment: Absolutely brilliant, solved a problem i've had for weeks and I didn't realise the calc function was so widely supported. Thank you!

Comment: The best solution. Thanks

Comment: awesome suggestion

Answer (score 48):

Similar to Bass, I had to also set the overflow-y.  That could actually be done in the CSS

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
    $('.modal .modal-body').css('overflow-y', 'auto'); 
    $('.modal .modal-body').css('max-height', $(window).height() * 0.7);
});
```

Comment: Works pretty well! Thanx!

Answer (score 31):

Try:

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
$('.modal-content').css('height',$( window ).height()*0.8);
});
```

Comment: Just in case as clarification, this just needs to come before `.modal('show')` command if that's used.

Comment: This is a good solution. Just don't forget to add css('overflow', 'auto') in case your content gets too large.

Comment: Would you mind explaining why the magic number `0.8`? Thanks!

Comment: because of the question asks for: "set the width and height of the whole modal window to 80% of the viewport". For 100% use 1, and so on

Answer (score 5):

To expand on Ryand's answer, if you're using Bootstrap.ui, this on your modal-instance will do the trick:

```
    modalInstance.rendered.then(function (result) {
        $('.modal .modal-body').css('overflow-y', 'auto'); 
        $('.modal .modal-body').css('max-height', $(window).height() * 0.7);
        $('.modal .modal-body').css('height', $(window).height() * 0.7);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to make modal use as much screen space as possible on phones. I've made a plugin to fix this UX problem of Bootstrap modals on mobile phones, you can check it out here - https://github.com/keaukraine/bootstrap-fs-modal

All you will need to do is to apply `modal-fullscreen` class and it will act similar to native screens of iOS/Android.

Answer (score 0):

I am using jquery for this. I mad a function to set desired height to the modal(You can change that according to your requirement).
Then I used Modal Shown event to call this function.
**Remember not to use `$("#modal").show()` rather use `$("#modal").modal('show')` otherwise shown.bs.modal will not be fired.**

That all I have for this scenario.

```js
var offset=250; //You can set offset accordingly based on your UI
function AdjustPopup() 
{
    $(".modal-body").css("height","auto");
    if ($(".modal-body:visible").height() > ($(window).height() - offset)) 
    {
        $(".modal-body:visible").css("height", ($(window).height() - offset));
    }
}
//Execute the function on every trigger on show() event.
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        AdjustPopup();
    });
});
//Remember to show modal like this
$("#MyModal").modal('show');
```