# Adding horizontal scroll bar for bootstrap modal body having <pre> tag content

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is the fiddle with the issue. http://jsfiddle.net/sheth/YE9Sx/
I am trying to have do a text viewer. I don't have the text as a document but as a JSON array of pages and lines. I decided using Bootstrap Modal and got the header and footer stationery with the document scrolling vertically between them for a single page.

To see the issue, click on the button and the modal will appear. If you scroll down, you will see the horizontal scroll bar attached to the <pre> tag. I want the horizontal scroll bar attached to the modal-body like the vertical scroll-bar and not to the <pre> tag. 
This is what I have so far

```
.report-modal-body {
    max-height: calc(100vh - 148px);
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x:auto;
}
.report-pre {
    width:100%;
    overflow-x:auto;
    word-wrap:normal;
}
```

For the max-height entry above please see the question [Fixed header position in bootstrap 3 modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21590213/fixed-header-position-in-bootstrap-3-modal)

Answer (score 3):

I got what I need by removing the div tag having style "**modal-body**" and attaching modal-body to the <pre>
The fiddle is here. http://jsfiddle.net/sheth/YE9Sx/8/

```
<pre class="report-pre modal-body report-modal-body">
```

Other option is to style the div tag having class modal-body so that is uses fixed width font and treats white-space as the pre tag

http://jsfiddle.net/sheth/YE9Sx/12/

```
<div class="modal-body report-modal-body">
.report-modal-body {
    max-height:calc(100vh - 150px);
    overflow-y:auto;
    overflow-x:auto;
    white-space:pre;
    font-family:monospace;
}
```