# How make a Bootstrap modal with scrollable content and max height?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal with a large content in it.
So I want the modal be the max-hight of my window and the content should be scrollable within the modal.

This is what my modal is right now:

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span>&times;</span></button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Error Log: {{ log_name }}</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <pre>
        {{ log_content }}
      </pre>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning pull-left" ng-click="clear_log( )"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" ng-click="refresh_log( )"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span></button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Twitter Bootstrap 3 Modal with Scrollable Body](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26807524/twitter-bootstrap-3-modal-with-scrollable-body)

Comment: give a very high value to the max-height in css of the modal div like `max-height:10000px;` and give the `height:auto` and `overflow-y:scroll`

Comment: i tried, but it's still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With pure CSS it's not possible, you can achieve the dynamic height of modal according to window size with following piece of script with suggested answer CSS  in comments;

Script

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
    $('pre').css('height',$( window ).height()*0.9);
});
```

CSS

```
.modal-body {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xcwdjdak/)

Note: You have to adjust the height and may be the target class which you want to be with dynamic height, in example I target `pre` you can also try with `$('.modal-body').css('height',$( window ).height()*0.9);` which ever suits your need and according to design.

Or you can totally remove CSS suggested above and set the height in JS like as follow;

```
$('pre').css('height',$( window ).height()*0.6);
```

**For Remote Modals**

With remote modals above solutions will not work so with remote modals if you want to adjust the height of the selector e.g `modal-body` then following script and CSS can do the trick with `bootstrap modal loaded event`

```
$('#myModal').on('loaded.bs.modal', function () {
    $('pre').css('height',$( window ).height()*0.6); 
});
```

CSS

```
.modal-body {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

[Bootstrap Modal events Functions](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events)