# Yii2 modal height issue

Tags: yii2, modal-dialog

I've been using bootstrap modal on some form. I have learned from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aUAUsADp9ao&t=300s) tutorial to create modal. For my previous project I didn't have any issue with the modal. But for my current project the modal body is not fully covering the modal content. Here's the screenshot
[image] 
I solved this problem for now by referring [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19140702/bootstrap-3-set-height-of-modal-window-according-to-screen-size). I'm not able to figure out what could be causing the height issue.

My view file code

```
<div class="collection-type-index">



<h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
<?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

<p>
    <?= Html::button('Create Collection', ['value' => Url::to('index.php?r=settings/collectiontype/create'), 'class' => 'btn btn-success', 'id' => 'modalButton']) ?>
</p>

        <?php // Modal for create
            Modal::begin([
                    'header'=>'Collection Type',
                    'id'=>'modal',
                    'size'=>'modal-lg',
            ]);

            echo "<div id='modalContent'></div>";

            Modal::end();

    ?> <!-- end modal -->

<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'id',
        'type',
        'days',
        'created_by',
        'modified_by',
        // 'status',

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

My controller create action code

```
public function actionCreate() {
        $model = new CollectionType();

        $model->created_by = Yii::$app->user->identity->username;
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
                return $this->renderAjax('create', ['model' => $model]);
            } else {
                return $this->render('create', ['model' => $model]);
            }
        }
}
```

And my js code

```
$(function(){
$('#modalButton').click(function(){
    $('#modal').modal('show')
        .find('#modalContent')
        .load($(this).attr('value'));
});

$('#modal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
    $('.modal-lg .modal-content').css('height',$( window ).height()*0.55);
});
});
```

As I said I've solved the problem by using the above js script but I don't think this is the best solution as I would have to set the height manually like this for every modal. What could be causing this problem? Has anyone faced this issue and solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a problem with floats. Modify the view generated inside the modal:

Wrap the content of this modal between `<div class="clearfix">` and `</div>`.

OR

Add `<div class="clearfix"></div>` at the end of this view.